# Can I control the destination title in iframe?

Tags: html, google-maps-embed

Is there any way to control the destination title, while embedding the map with an iframe? For `origin` I use Postcode (which is fine to show), but for `destination` whatever I use, `lat-lon` or `Store name + address + town + country`, I get **wrong destination title in 80% or cases**. I would like to show my own title for Destination, is it possible?

Here is the example embed code ([docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start)):

```
<iframe 
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=MYKEY&amp;origin=ORIGIN&amp;destination=DESTINATION"
></iframe>
```

What I want to control:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it in parentheses like so:

```
<iframesrc="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=MYKEY&amp;origin=ORIGIN&amp;destination=DESTINATION+(My%20Business%20Name)"></iframe>
```

Comment: Ah, it was long time ago, cannot check it now, hope it works?